# Generating PDFs in VB.NET 2005

Tags: vb.net, pdf-generation

I am having a problem while generating a PDF doc, the text which I want to show in the PDF doc exceeds the PDF paper range. How can I adjust the text to fit the page range?

This is a sample of my code that shows some questions and answers:

```
    Dim PDF As PDFCreatorPilotLib.PDFDocument3
    ' create pdf library object
    PDF = New PDFCreatorPilotLib.PDFDocument3
    ' initialize PDF Engine
    PDF.StartEngine("demo@demo", "demo")
    ' set filename

    PDF.FileName = "TestVB.PDF"
    PDF.AutoLaunch = True ' auto-open generated pdf document

    ' start document generation
    PDF.BeginDoc()

    PDF.PDFPAGE_SetActiveFont("Verdana", True, False, False, False, 9, 0)
    PDF.PDFPAGE_TextOut(80, 270, 0, Label5.Text)
    PDF.PDFPAGE_TextOut(100, 270, 0, Questions1TextBox.Text)
    PDF.PDFPAGE_TextOut(80, 300, 0, Label3.Text)
    PDF.PDFPAGE_TextOut(100, 300, 0, Answers1TextBox.Text)

    PDF.PDFPAGE_TextOut(80, 330, 0, Label6.Text)
    PDF.PDFPAGE_TextOut(100, 330, 0, TextBox14.Text)
    PDF.PDFPAGE_TextOut(80, 360, 0, Label4.Text)
    PDF.PDFPAGE_TextOut(100, 360, 0, TextBox1.Text)

    PDF.PDFPAGE_TextOut(80, 390, 0, Label7.Text)
    PDF.PDFPAGE_TextOut(100, 390, 0, TextBox12.Text)
    PDF.PDFPAGE_TextOut(80, 420, 0, Label4.Text)
    PDF.PDFPAGE_TextOut(100, 420, 0, TextBox1.Text)

    ' finalize document generation
    PDF.EndDoc()
End Sub
```

Comment: Please specify which library you are using to generate the PDF.

Comment: Iam using PDF Creator Pilot Type Library,